# Can i attach the image with control bar in videojs-overlay

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, video.js

I want to show the image in video-js-overlay only when screen size is maximum and hide it when user hit 'Esc' button.Currently i have the following screens:

> **This is the modal screen i want to hide picture from here.**
>   [image]
>
> **This is the full screen and picture is perfectly place.**
>   [image]

I m following the https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-overlay.
I have seen that when i pause the video image from both screen hide it. But i can't hide the image from modal screen. Any suggestion or clue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I m following the https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-overlay but i m unable to hide it with control bar any help would be great.

Comment: hi @waheed shah, could you help me regarding how you added overlay image in full screen mode

Comment: hey @krishna i have answered this question my self! add the code which i shared below and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using the VideoJS fullscreen event handler.Follow this https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-overlay. Add a style to header file

```
<style>.hide-overlay .vjs-overlay {
    display: none;
}</style>
```

And by adding script to your main page.

```
if (!player.isFullscreen()) {

       player.addClass("hide-overlay");
  }else{

       player.removeClass("hide-overlay");
  }
});
```

This may help someone using video.js library.